# Ruby throws an error message "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass" with ERB code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in cloud 9 IDE and Ruby is throwing an error message "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass" with the following code.  What am I missing?

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
       <% if @post.errors.any? %>
           <div id="errors">
               <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving</h2>
               <ul>
                   <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                       <li><%= msg %></li>
                   <% end %>
               </ul>
           </div>`enter code here`
       <% end %>
```

Comment: @post is nil. that's your main error. Provide the controller code for us to help debug

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors to fix

```
<%= form_for @post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
```

instead of this:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
```

Also you have to make sure you have `@post` assigned in your controller.